# How do I display a specific field from an entity reference within a custom block template?

Tags: blocks

I have a custom block type that only has one field: an entity reference to my news content type. I am trying to display two specific fields from the news content type but can't figure it out.

This entity reference field has a machine name of `field_featured_news`

I have created a file with the filename **block--block-content-testnews.html.twig**

In this file, I can use `{{ content }}` and it will render the full entity (based on the settings in Manage Display.

However, I can't access the image field that is within the news content type. The field's machine name is called `field_featured_news_image`.

I have tried adding the following to no avail:

`{{ content.field_featured_news_image }}`
`{{ content.field_featured_news_image.0 }}`
`{{ content.field_featured_news_image.entity.uri.value }}`

and many others.

Only `{{ content }}` will display anything but it's the entire news node.

Comment: In the code, replace the word "node" with "block" from the accepted answer.

Comment: `{{ block.field_featured_news.0.entity.field_featured_news_image.0.value }}`

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but that didn't work. Nothing loaded.

Comment: You flushed the cache?